# Hibernate Query not executing

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have a Java web application based on Struts2 and Hibernate framework. Back end database is postgresql. Application hangs abruptly. As per logs I can acknowledge that Query method does not execute.

The following code is used to fetch data using query.
Please suggest if there is another way of using Query to fetch data from the database.

```
@Override
public List<Object[]> getLovServiceSqlParam(String query, Object[] obj) {
    Session session = null;

    if (this.getHibernateTemplate() != null && query != null && query.length() > 0) {           
        try {
            session = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
            SQLQuery query1 = session.createSQLQuery(query);

            for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
                query1.setParameter(i, obj[i]);
            }
            result = query1.list();
            session.close();
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `hibernateTemplate` by Spring framework like [described here (Spring Hibernate Integration Using HibernateDaoSupport)](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-dao-support/).